# Access denied 403 error for downloading landsat 8 from AWS3 via curl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, gdal

I have this script which should be able to download a Landsat 8 scene from AWS S3 `usgs-landsat` with a paid user.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


#!/bin/bash

# Path to your test file
req_path="/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2023/233/245/LC08_L2SP_233245_20230510_20230518_02_T2/LC08_L2SP_233245_20230510_20230518_02_T2_SR_B1.TIF"

# We need the current date to calculate the signature and also to pass to S3/GCS
curr_date=`date -R`

# This is the name of your S3/GCS bucket
bucket_name="usgs-landsat"
string_to_sign="GET\n\n\n${curr_date}\n/${bucket_name}${req_path}"

# Your secret (this one works fine when I used aws cli command)
secret="qc2Kc...."

# Your S3 key (this one works fine when I used aws cli command)
s3_key="AKIAY..."

# We will now calculate the signature to be sent as a header.
signature=$(echo -en "${string_to_sign}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${secret}" -binary | base64)

# That's all we need. Now we can make the request as follows.


# S3
curl -v -H "Host: ${bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
        -H "Date: $curr_date" \
        -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3_key}:${signature}" \
         "https://${bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com${req_path}"
```

But the output when running the command is:

```
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2023 01:00:40 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
< 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
* Connection #0 to host usgs-landsat.s3.amazonaws.com left intact
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>9AST0DFVKK34KFW8</RequestId><HostId>dFyJ9kCQeeWVEnB8WoXbHpZhsloRmqm1Mc3yY7WP90ZWhrOk02J7Vxe1ci9/3bvu59soxAYx6pU=</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: That bucket requires requestor pays, you'll need to add `x-amz-request-payer:requester\n` after the date in your string to sign, and the corresponding header to the curl request with `-H "x-amz-request-payer: requester"`

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks, actually, I wanted to use gdal tool for accessing the file. And your hint shows exactly like from Even's at: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2023-July/057429.html